# SharePoint 2010 training, any recommendations?

Tags: development, learning, training

i am looking for a SP 2010 training in Midwest area, any recommendations?

Comment: Are you looking for end-user, administrator, or developer training?

Comment: And where in the Midwest? (What city?)

Comment: i set this Q as community wiki as it has multiple answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Critical Path Training has some top notch training courses for both developers, admins and information workers.

Check [here](http://www.criticalpathtraining.com/Locations/Pages/default.aspx) if they have something in your general area.

Answer (score 1):

[Mindsharp](http://www.mindsharp.com) also has some great training.